# How to increase the maximum semaphore limit on MacOS/BSD

Tags: c, macos, multiprocessing, semaphore, bsd

I want to increase the maximum number of semaphores that can be opened at the same time.

I know that the current limit can be retrieved via

```
long nsems_max = sysconf(_SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX);
```

or from the console via

```
ipcs -S

semmap:     30  (# of entries in semaphore map)
semmni:      8  (# of semaphore identifiers)
semmns:    128  (# of semaphores in system)
semmnu:      0  (# of undo structures in system)
semmsl:  87381  (max # of semaphores per id)
semopm:      5  (max # of operations per semop call)
semume:     10  (max # of undo entries per process)
semusz:     32  (size in bytes of undo structure)
semvmx:  32767  (semaphore maximum value)
semaem:  16384  (adjust on exit max value)
```

On Linux the limit can be changed by manually editing

```
/proc/sys/kernel/sem
```

but this doesn't work for MacOS/BSD. How to change/increase the limit on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following variables are editable via `/usr/sbin/sysctl` (available for your current session), or you can create a **plist** to always set the values on reboot.  You must create the file.

```
sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/sysctl.plist`
```

Set them as your heart desires.

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/sysctl.plist**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>sysctl</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
   <string>/usr/sbin/sysctl</string>
   <string>-w</string>
   <string>kern.sysv.semmni=87381</string>
   <string>kern.sysv.semmns=87381</string>
   <string>kern.sysv.semmnu=87381</string>
   <string>kern.sysv.semmsl=87381</string>
   <string>kern.sysv.semume=10</string>
   <string>kern.posix.sem.max=10000</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/sysctl.plist
```

Comment: `/usr/sbin/sysctl -a | grep sem` gave me the list.

Comment: I don't have a file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/sysctl.plist` but setting the value directly via `sudo sysctl kern.sysv.semmns=88888` did the trick. At least for the current session. The values will reset after reboot. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make that clear.  You MAKE a `/Library/LaunchDaemons/sysctl.plist`.  Setting the value via `sysctl` will not survive a reboot.

Comment: Editing at least the `kern.sysv.semume` variable with `/usr/sbin/sysctl` does not work on my Mac M1:
```
sudo /usr/sbin/sysctl -w kern.sysv.semume=100
kern.sysv.semume: 10
sysctl: kern.sysv.semume=100: Invalid argument
```